# How to compare colors in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want change button background for different state.
I try so:

```
 @IBAction func addToShedulerAction(sender: UIButton) {   
       println(sender.backgroundColor)     
        if sender.backgroundColor==UIColor.redColor(){
            sender.backgroundColor==UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
        else //if sender.backgroundColor==UIColor.whiteColor()
        {
            sender.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }
```

but in first push button  println print nil and background change to red, in second push println print "Optional(UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1)" and color doesn't change

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970475/how-to-compare-uicolors

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't compare colors using the `==` operator. You do it like this and you need the `!` to unwrap the optional color:

```
if sender.backgroundColor!.isEqual(UIColor.redColor()) {
            
}
```

Also, remove the extraneous `=` in your assignment statement. It should be:

```
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 28):

Previous answers are wrong
cause

```
UIColor.black.isEqual(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
```

returns `false`

add this code to your project (Swift 4)

```
extension UIColor {
  static func == (l: UIColor, r: UIColor) -> Bool {
    var r1: CGFloat = 0
    var g1: CGFloat = 0
    var b1: CGFloat = 0
    var a1: CGFloat = 0
    l.getRed(&r1, green: &g1, blue: &b1, alpha: &a1)
    var r2: CGFloat = 0
    var g2: CGFloat = 0
    var b2: CGFloat = 0
    var a2: CGFloat = 0
    r.getRed(&r2, green: &g2, blue: &b2, alpha: &a2)
    return r1 == r2 && g1 == g2 && b1 == b2 && a1 == a2
  }
}
func == (l: UIColor?, r: UIColor?) -> Bool {
  let l = l ?? .clear
  let r = r ?? .clear
  return l == r
}
```

so now

```
UIColor.black == UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
```

returns `true`

and for you:

```
if sender.backgroundColor == .red {
  sender.backgroundColor = .white
} else {
  sender.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

now your code looks pretty :)

Comment: Comparing CGFloats with == is not a good idea. In floating point values it is better to use inequalities or a subtraction with a threshold (delta).

Comment: Note that this only changes the behaviour of `==`, not `!=`, so you'll need to either implement `!=` as well, or remember to always use `!(color1 == color2)` rather than `color1 != color2`

Comment: Also one needs to write `func == (l: UIColor, r: UIColor?) -> Bool` where only `r` is nullable

Answer (score 0):

**Remember** when you are **comparing** UIColors you have to write description at the end of the color for both side, if you don't write this, every time it will enter into else block. For Example, see the below code

```
if(ocularPlus1Btn.backgroundColor?.description == UIColor.init(red: 23.0 / 255.0, green: 82 / 255.0, blue: 84 / 255.0, alpha: 1).description) {
   return "positive"
} else {
   return "negative"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a mistake in your first `if` clause. It should be:

```
if sender.backgroundColor.isEqual(UIColor.redColor()){
    sender.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor // only one '=' here
}
```

Comment: That is not how you compare UIColors.