# Replacing NSAttributedString attributes by tags

Tags: ios, swift3, nsstring, nsattributedstring, xcode8

I have a text view which takes in black and blue text. Now I need to pass it to server by adding special tags (`__BLACK__ and __BLUE__`) to each texts. So, for eg in below image if my text is 
[image]

The sending string should be `__BLUE__Hi__/BLUE__ __BLACK__this__/BLACK__ __BLUE__is__/BLUE__ __BLACK__John__/BLACK__`

So, when I get it back from server I can identify which are black and blue and apply attributes for the same.

At the moment if I print the description of the attributed string it looks like below

```
Hi {
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7ffbdfd10ce0> font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}this {
    NSColor = "UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7ffbdfd10ce0> font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}is {
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7ffbdfd10ce0> font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}John{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7ffbdfd10ce0> font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}
```

How do I identify from this which text should be marked as `__BLACK__ and __BLUE__` ?

Comment: Look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027651/convert-attributed-string-to-simple-tagged-html/44051956#44051956, enumerate on `NSForegroundAttributeName` (instead of `NSFontAttributeName`), read the color and add your special tag.

Comment: you can convert NSAttributedString to html and save into database or send it to api and you can easily retrieve from HTML string to NSAttributedString back

Comment: May add this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559937/how-to-compare-colors-in-swift because of difference color spaces.