# How to compare two colours variable have same color

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have two colors variable 1.) is colorArray 2.) is color variable
I need to compare on which index of array matched with color variable

I tried with what color is available in my color variable is have available in colorArray or not

```
let colorSource:[UIColor] = [UIColor.init(red: 255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1),
                             UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1),
                             UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1),
                             UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1),
                             UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1),
                             UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1),
                             UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 100/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1),
                             UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)]
```

colorSource is color array

//This is variable and the red, blue and green value I am getting from api

```
var color = UIColor.init(red: CGFloat(red)/255, green: CGFloat(green)/255, blue: CGFloat(blue)/255, alpha: 1)
```

Now I want in my collection view cell the color matched with index it's cell color will stroke the boarder

```
   if color == colorSource[indexPath.row] {
        print("Hi")
    }
```

the above code is not executing

Comment: see this for help :[How to compare colors in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559937/how-to-compare-colors-in-swift)