# Check button backgroundColor in if statement

Tags: ios, if-statement, background-color, uicolor, uibackgroundcolor

I'm trying to set if condition on the basis of button background color. I've found a solution on stackoverflow but it's not for me because what I'm doing different is my buttons are in an array and `if` condition is in a `for` loop. It's like checking all the buttons in the array every time a button is tapped and if any button have background color as black don't show the next `interface`.
This method is setting those color which is doing good.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    [buttonsArray[i] setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

Now the problem is in this method:

```
-(void)myFunction
{   
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if([buttonsArray[i] backgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]])
        {
            //code I want to use if the condition is true
        }}}
```

I've also tried the following conditions in if:

```
 if([buttonsArray[i].backgroundColor isequal:[UIColor blackColor]])
//or
if([[buttons[i] background] isEqual:myBlack])
//or
if([buttonsArray[i] backgroundColor]==[UIColor blackColor])
```

Please not that I'm using `setColor` to set the color not `setBackgroundColor` and I want to keep it that way because this is a requirement.

Comment: You can refer this question for better choices of answers.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970475/how-to-compare-uicolors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the colour of the button, you should have another array which contains an `NSNumber` (or a custom class) that holds the state of each button. This will be easy to use and test. Trying to use the UI to hold your model state will always lead to issues like this.

Comment: nice suggestion. Let me give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking button using color, go for Tags.
Use tags to set a specific numeric id for a button and you can use the same throughout the code. Like this,

```
myButton.tag=1;
myButton.tag=2;
```

**OR**

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    [buttonsArray[i] setTag:i];
}
```

or you can set tag in interface builder properties of button.