# How to make if loop which compares color?

Tags: ios, swift, loops, if-statement

I would like to ask how can I make an if-statement which compares color? Mine doesn't work...

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(10, 
    animations: { 
        self.labelTen.layer.backgroundColor = self.timeOneColor.CGColor 
    }
)

if(self.labelTen.backgroundColor == timeOneColor)
{
    print("something")
}
```

Comment: Where is the loop in your code? If this is just about comparing UIColor objects for equality check [How to compare UIColors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970475/how-to-compare-uicolors)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work?" As it's currently written, it's difficult to tell what exactly your problem is.

Comment: I'm just trying to compare colors but nothing works for me yet.

Comment: What doesn't work?  It doesn't compile?  It crashes?  It produces unexpected results?  It launches missiles?  [Does Not Work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) is not an acceptable description of your problem.

Comment: For example if I use "if (CGColorEqualToColor(self.labelTen.backgroundColor.CGColor, timeOneColor.CGColor))" everything is okey(there's no errors), but nothing happens not even print("something")

Comment: There's no print statement in your code, so I'd be surprised if it printed anything at all. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You need to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36680748/edit) to include all of the details including a reasonable description of what you expect to happen, what does happen, what the inputs are, and how your expected & actual results differ.

Comment: Ok guys, I found a solution. The problem was that a backgroundColor was not a CGColor. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specifically compare colors you can check it by following method

```
if (CGColorEqualToColor(self.labelTen.backgroundColor.CGColor, timeOneColor.CGColor))
{
    //Two colors are same
}
```

Return true if color1 is equal to color2; false otherwise.