# How to filter UIColor object in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I am generating random colors and storing in `NSmutableArray` like this

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    UIColor *c = [self colorGen];
    [_cArray addObject:c];
}
```

I want to check that every time I add color to array its not repeating, How I apply predicate to `_cArray` to check color return by `[self colorGen]` method is not already exist in `_cArray`, for example `_cArray` already contains red color after 10 iteration `[self colorGen]` again return red color so how I can avoid adding it again my array.

Comment: Use a set instead and don't stop generating until the set contains 1000 objects?  The show-stopper, however, is how close a colour needs to be in order to be considered "equal" (i.e. you want to compare within a given range as floating point numbers don't play nice in comparisons).

Comment: Please give a snippet thank you

Comment: No I cannot be bothered.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        UIColor *c = [self colorGen];

      if (![_cArray containsObject:c]) {

           [_cArray addObject:c];

        }  
}
```

plz use this code

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableSet *colors = [NSMutableSet set];
while (colors.count < 1000) {
    [colors addObject:[self colorGen]];
}
```

example code for the way `UIColor` objects are compared:

```
NSMutableSet *colors = [NSMutableSet set];

UIColor *color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.2 blue:0.3 alpha:1];
UIColor *color2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.2 blue:0.3 alpha:1];

[colors addObjectsFromArray:@[color1, color2]];

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)colors.count);
```

this code prints **1** indicating that both colors are treated to be equal!

Comment: i do not see anything that is identical... i'm using a set instead of array as well as a while loop instead of a for loop...

Comment: But of course there is the small matter of `100` and providing a better "comparison" (one with an epsilon).  Then you're answer would be perfect.

Comment: 1000 is causing memory issue and terminating the app

Comment: how do I compare the existing colors?

Comment: you should not need to compare the colors since a set does not allow you to put the same color into the array twice... what are you trying to achieve by putting that many color objects into a set / array?

Comment: No.  See my comment to the question.  The issue is "what is equal"? Is colour `{ 0.1233, 0.879, 0.233 }` the same as `{ 0.1233, 0.879, 0.234 }` or not?  Only the OP can really answer that, however for me there should be a difference of, say, 0.1 across all values in order to be considered "not equal".

Comment: OK, I don't seem to be able to make myself understood.  Nevermind.

Comment: well... the set itself compares an object that should be added with the objects it already contains. in my example code i try to add two objects (color1 and color2). the log statement (after the adding call) tells us that the set contains only one object (although i tried to insert two objects). so you can tell that it treated both color objects to be equal and only added the first of them. hope i could help... :P

Answer (score 0):

you can do like,

```
 for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    UIColor *c = [self colorGen];

    if (![_cArray containsObject:c] ) {

         [_cArray addObject:c];

    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"already there");
    }


}
```

Comment: make increment operation in else condition so will get 1000 objects

Comment: I could be wrong, but won't `[self colorGen]` always return a new object, so using `containsObject` isn't going to find a match? You probably need to use something from these answers to match colours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970475/how-to-compare-uicolors

Comment: @Flexicoder `containsObject:` will invoke `isEqual:` in order to determine if the object exists, it won't use `==` on the instance pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Change in methods colorGen it should return hex value of UIColor

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; ) {
    NSString *strCode = [self colorGen];

    if (![_cArray containsObject:strCode] ) {

         [_cArray addObject:strCode];
        i++;

    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"already there");
    }


}
```