# How to check a button color change from one color to another

Tags: ios, swift

In the screenshot posted below, the *cook*, *buyer* and *both* are `UIButton`. User can click any one button. If one button is pressed, the button background color changes to green. After that when user clicks the register button, how do I check if the `UIButton` color is green or not. At least one `UIButton`has to be selected in order for the user to register.

[image]

I changed the button background color using this code:

```
@IBAction func cookact(_ sender: Any){

    cookbtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

How do I check if a button has been pressed?

Comment: As you can take one var which will save `tag` of any button clicked and when register you can compare tag values

Comment: Hi piyushrathi, How can I compared the tag values.. can you explain the coding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970475/how-to-compare-uicolors -  check this

Comment: You can directly compare the color values or you can use a 3 different bool values and use them as required.

Comment: Check the situation of a button through the color I do not think it is the best option. You can use a tag as comments PiyushRathi or use another property even if it is not the button. The tag is a property that has the button and you access with boton.tag = Int depending on the tag value you are doing one thing or another

Comment: @mouni is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes it's resolved @ piyushRathi :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it. One assigning the tag values to buttons and compare, Other easy solution is by declaring the enum values:

Declare the enum:

```
Swift:
    enum REGISTER_TYPE {
            case COOK
            case BUYER
            case BOTH
        }

Objective - C
    typedef enum {
    COOK = 1,
    BUYER = 2, 
    BOTH = 3
    }REGISTER_TYPE;
```

Now In your ViewController, create a property for the enum REGISTER_TYPE as

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) REGISTER_TYPE registerType;
```

When onClick the Button Action assign value to a property as

```
@IBAction func cookact(_ sender: Any){
   self.registerType = COOK
}



@IBAction func buyeract(_ sender: Any){
       self.registerType = BUYER
    }
```

So, self.registerType variable always holds a type of registration.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @mouni refer this answer, he answers what I told you in my comment.

Comment: Thank you so much... @ Imad ali ans @piyushRathi

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bool value.When the user presses the cook button or buyer button,you can change this bool value to true and on the basis of this bool value you can determine wether the button was clicked or not.